# Using DistanceMatrixService within Google Apps Script

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, distance

From a GAS, is it possible to call Maps API services such as DistanceMatrix?

I'd like to calculate distance between addresses stored in a spreadsheet. 
I suppose displaying a map is required, to comply with terms of the Maps API.

Would something like the following be possible?

```
var service = new Maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins: [OAddresses],
    destinations: [DAddresses],
    travelMode: Maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: Maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you..It is the complete code with file parsing.
It skips 1st row because of headings.
please change "**sheet name**" according to your need.
Check the screenshot for better understanding.
*ScreenShot:* https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5nG8jqFwu2eMk9uajZJX2VhRjg/edit

```
function geoDistance() {
var sheetName           = 'xyz';
var activeSpreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var selectedSheet       = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var sheet               = selectedSheet; 
var lastRow             = sheet.getLastRow();
var N                   = lastRow;

for (var i=2;i<=N;i++){
var startpoint          = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
var endpoint            = sheet.getRange(i, 2, 1, 1).getValue();

var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
 .setOrigin(startpoint)
 .setDestination(endpoint)
 .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
 .getDirections();

var print = sheet.getRange(i,3,1,1).setValue(directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
}}
```